# How can I copy Hubspot Custom Objects data into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, custom-object, hubspot-crm

I have few custom objects in HubSpot.
I am unable to sync those objects' data into Snowflake as snowflake does not support custom objects.

Hubspot now releases Custom Objects APIs.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you provide more details for the use case which you are facing issue with? As in some example from hubspot and what exactly do you imply by "sync" to Snowflake.

Comment: Hi Srinath,
Sorry, I should have been more clear. So we are using Fivetran to sync HubSpot data into our Snowflake Datawarehouse.In HubSpot we have some custom objects and FiveTran is unable to sync data from custom objects into SnowFlake.So I am looking for solution or alternative of that.